# Xcode's default projects folder missing

Tags: xcode8

I'm quite new in iOS development and right now I'm watching tutorial videos. In them I see that every time a new project is created, Xcode suggests /home/Xcode as root destination where you can store your project. This folder has even a special icon with the Xcode logo on it.
On my Mac this folder is missing. I still can save the project elsewhere but even after re-installing Xcode that folder is missing.

Any idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The /home/Xcode folder is not the default location to store Xcode projects. The home folder is hidden by default on macOS so I suggest choosing a different folder to store your projects.

It does not matter where you save your Xcode projects. Save them wherever you want on your computer.